# Database migration failed on docker for flask Api

Tags: postgresql, docker, flask, docker-compose, flask-migrate

I have my flask api that uses a postgresql database. When trying to deploy my api even locally using docker-compose and docker. The database migrations are not successful. How to fix it. I have put the repo for the running project here: [flaskA Api](https://github.com/benmhamed-a/testFlask)